# .net MVC 3.0 file upload with progress bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jquery, file-upload, progress-bar

I saw there are similar question to this. But I couldn't find an answer. That's why I am posting this again. Sorry!!

I want to build a file uploader with percentage bar with in it using .net mvc 3.0

There are some jquery plugins. But they need html 5 support. I am trying to build it without html 5 support.

Currently what I do is upload files with Ajax support. When file is uploaded by user I make an ajax request and display loading.gif until requested completed. So it is a pretty strait forward code for simple image uploads.

Now I am trying to upload videos and send it to [Vimeo](http://developer.vimeo.com/) through their REST APIs.

I could do the same thing. But since files are large I want to do it in a nice way.

My code is something like this

View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            UpdateTargetId = "form1",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            OnBegin = "ajaxValidate",
                            OnSuccess = "getGbPostSuccess",
                            OnFailure = "showFaliure"
                        }))
      //.......
      //rest of the form
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
     //Read file 
     //Post file to Vimeo (this is the part that take time to upload)
     //get uploaded video content
     return PartialView("xxxxx", Model); // return uploaded Video
}
```

I display a loading.gif using a small piece of javascript while this process happening. This code is working absolutely fine. As I mention before I want to make it more user friendly by putting a percentage progress bar.
Hope my question is clear.

Please help me...

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Ajax Multiple file upload script with Progress bar, Drag and Drop mvc](http://lesson8.blogspot.com/2012/09/ajax-multiple-file-upload-script-with.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But they need html 5 support.

Not necessary. For example the [blueimp file upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin tests browser capabilities and could use the [*jQuery iframe transport*](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js#files) if the browser doesn't support HTML5 XHR2. Here are [more details](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support) about browser support.

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is another example which uses Flash if the browser doesn't suport XHR2.

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is yet another very powerful plugin which supports a multitude of equivalents if the browser doesn't support XHR2.

So just pick a plugin, read the documentation, integrate it in your ASP.NET MVC 3 application and have fun.